# Query returns zero records in coldfusion context, but works fine in Navicat

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I've got a query that's returning zero records when I load a page.  If I copy and paste that same query (from the debug output) into navicat, I get rows returned (as I expect).  Has anyone seen this?  It happens locally (CF9) AND remotely on our staging server (CF10).  Even weirder, it's a query that was previously working fine - I simply added an if statement to the where clause, and all of a sudden...

Here's the query:

```
    SELECT
        a.EncounterProductID,
        a.DateTime AS ServiceDate,
        aa.CartItemID,
        aaa.CartID,
        aaaaa.CartStatus,
        b.ProductID,
        b.ProductName,
        b.CPTCode,
        b.Price,
        c.EncounterID,
        c.DateTimeClosed AS EncounterClosedDate,
        d.FirstName,
        d.LastName
    FROM
        EncounterProducts a
            LEFT JOIN CartItemProduct aa ON (a.EncounterProductID = aa.EncounterProductID AND aa.Active = 1)
            LEFT JOIN CartItem aaa ON (aa.CartItemID = aaa.CartItemID)
            LEFT JOIN Cart aaaa ON (aaa.CartID = aaaa.CartID)
            LEFT JOIN CartStatus aaaaa ON (aaaa.CartStatusID = aaaaa.CartStatusID),
        Product b,
        Encounters c,
        Contacts d,
        EncounterStatuses e
    WHERE
        1 = 1
        AND (aa.CartItemID IS NULL OR aaaaa.CartStatus = 'Deleted')
        AND a.Active = 1
        AND a.ProductID = b.ProductID
        AND a.EncounterID = c.EncounterID
        AND c.PatientID = d.ContactID
        AND c.EncounterStatusID = e.EncounterStatusID
        AND e.EncounterStatus = 'Closed'
      <CFIF IsDefined("ARGUMENTS.encounter") AND IsObject(ARGUMENTS.encounter)>
             AND c.EncounterID = <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.encounter.getID()#">
     <CFELSE>
            AND c.DateTimeClosed >= <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#ARGUMENTS.startDate#">
            AND c.DateTimeClosed < <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#DateFormat(DateAdd('d', 1, ARGUMENTS.endDate), 'yyyy-mm-dd')# 00:00:00">
       </CFIF>
        AND c.LocationID = <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.locationID#">
        AND c.CustomerID = <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.customerID#">
    </CFQUERY>
```

All of this worked just fine before I added the lines:

```
<CFIF IsDefined("ARGUMENTS.encounter") AND IsObject(ARGUMENTS.encounter)>
    AND c.EncounterID = <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.encounter.getID()#">
<CFELSE>
    AND c.DateTimeClosed >= <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#ARGUMENTS.startDate#">
    AND c.DateTimeClosed < <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#DateFormat(DateAdd('d', 1, ARGUMENTS.endDate), 'yyyy-mm-dd')# 00:00:00">
</CFIF>
```

Previously, it had just been:

```
AND c.DateTimeClosed >= <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#ARGUMENTS.startDate#">
AND c.DateTimeClosed < <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#DateFormat(DateAdd('d', 1, ARGUMENTS.endDate), 'yyyy-mm-dd')# 00:00:00">
```

With no IF/ELSE statement.

Anyone seen anything like this before?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely don't need the `dateFormat` ... CF should recognize the result of the `dateAdd` and send the correct format to the DB. Have you tried turning on debugging and copying the query and params exactly from CF and running against the DB in another tool?

Comment: why are you mixing `JOIN` syntax? You have ANSI joins and then joins via commas

Comment: Can you post the sql from the two queries: 1) raw debug output and 2) navicat query? Last I checked you cannot directly copy and paste queries involving cfqueryparam. So silly question, are you sure it is not just a copy paste difference.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with the layout of these discussions, so I don't know how to directly respond to a given suggestion.  So, I'll address all of these here:  David - I didn't put this in the post, though I obviously should have.  The surrounding if-statement is evaluating to true, so the lines regarding dates aren't being in included in the query.  So, while you're points may be valid, they're not pertinant in this case.  Sorry I left that info out.

Comment: Bluefeet - I'm afraid I don't understand what you're getting at.  I'm not great with sql, so could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Leigh, you are correct - you can't directly copy and paste.  But, you can copy the replace the parameterized values with the values that debug tells you CF is replacing them with.  I've compared them line-by-line, and I assure you they are the same.

Also check my response to Miguel's suggestion below.  If I put the query in a different CF context it works fine!  Weird.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @JonathanP - Well the *exact same query* is not going to return different results, unless maybe caching is involved? You mentioned storing the query/function in an "Application object". Can you post that code?

Answer (score 1):

I see two different parts to your question.

**PART 1** You stated:

> it's a query that was previously working fine - I simply added an if statement to the where clause, and all of a sudden...

Obviously this leads me to believe that your new if condition is the culprit for the query no longer returning the results it was returning before.

The query was working with:

```
AND c.DateTimeClosed >= <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#ARGUMENTS.startDate#">
AND c.DateTimeClosed < <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#DateFormat(DateAdd('d', 1, ARGUMENTS.endDate), 'yyyy-mm-dd')# 00:00:00">
```

So now I assume it is passing your new if condition and instead the code is running this which is not returning results:

```
AND c.EncounterID = <CFQUERYPARAM cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.encounter.getID()#">
```

Is the #ARGUMENTS.encounter.getID()# returning what you expect?  Does the Encounters table actually contain records with that encounter id?

**PART 2** You stated:

> If I copy and paste that same query (from the debug output) into navicat, I get rows returned (as I expect).

I suspect you can't directly copy and paste the debug output and have it work without some modification.  You have to at least enter the values for the parameterized inputs.  So what values are you inputting when you run the query from navicat?  Are those the same values that ColdFusion is generating when it runs?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  To answer the first part, yes, the getID function is returning a value I'd expect to see.  And yes, that record exists.  Part 2: You're correct, I can't copy and past directly, but it works fine when I replace the parameterized inputs with the actual numerical values I see in the debug output.  And yes, they are the same as when CF is generating them.

Comment: Here's another oddity.  This query normally lives in function in an Application object, and in this context, I'm seeing the problem as described.  If, however, I move the query to a test file and load that file - I see the records as expected.  So weird.

Comment: @JonathanP, based on your comment there is nothing wrong with the query.  So now I am curious how you are referencing your query in the Application scope.  Can you share the function that contains this query and/or how you are defining it in the Application scope?  Just edit your original question with the new information please.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
#DateFormat(DateAdd('d', 1, ARGUMENTS.endDate), 'yyyy-mm-dd')# 00:00:00
```

with this:

```
#createODBCDateTime(DateAdd('d', 1, ARGUMENTS.endDate))#
```

Comment: Agreed there is no need `dateFormat`. But `createODBCDateTime` is redundant too as `DateAdd` already returns a date object.

Comment: I've had mixed results with MySQL and the date format it expects.  I always use the CreateODBCDateTime function and I've never had issues.  I've seen similar problems with Informix DBs as well.  MS SQL is pretty well behaved, though.

Comment: I have only run into problems when using strings, because then the interpretation is left up to the database. But as long as you are passing a date *object*, not a string, you should never have any problems.

Comment: ... it certainly won't break anything. But with the existing code `<cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_date" value="#createODBCDateTime(DateAdd(..))#">` you have three layers all returning date objects: dateAdd, createODBCDateTime and cfqueryparam. So the `createODBCDateTime` could be safely eliminated.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  The line you're concerned with isn't a concern in this particular instance because the surrounding if statement is evaluating as true in this circumstance.  I should've made that a part of my post.